# Error: Call to a member function in Yii

Tags: php, yii

I have a problem when used Yii, my code is:

```
Yii::app()->cache->set('idModel','1', 3600);
```

And I get this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function set() on a non-object

Comment: you need to configure a cache application component. take a look at [http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/caching.overview](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/caching.overview)

Comment: Thank @alfa6661 very much, it worked. But on host still working althought i not configure cache application component (error only happen when i used localhost) :).